# How to find max and min in an alphanumeric data array in Excel?

Tags: excel, max, min, alphanumeric

I have the following kind of data

```
A1          B1              C1              D1
II Cm2 447  I Phy Hn 60     II Cm2 457      I Phy Hn 70
II Cm2 448  I Phy Hn 61     II Cm2 458      I Phy Hn 71
II Cm2 449  I Phy Hn 62     II Cm2 459      I Phy Hn 72
II Cm2 450  I Phy Hn 63     II Cm2 460      I Phy Hn 73
II Cm2 451  I Phy Hn 64     II Cm2 461      I Phy Hn 74
II Cm2 452  I Phy Hn 65     II Cm2 462      I Phy Hn 75
II Cm2 453  I Phy Hn 66     II Cm2 463      I PHY ml 76
II Cm2 454  I Phy Hn 67     II Cm2 464      I PHY ml 77
II Cm2 455  I Phy Hn 68     II Cm2 465      I PHY ml 78
II Cm2 456  I Phy Hn 69     II Cm2 466      I PHY ml 79
```

Need to find Minimum and Maximum corresponding to '**II Cm2**', '**I Phy Hn**' and '**I PHY ml**'

Please Help.

The solution I am looking at

```
Grid           Min      Max
II Cm2         447      466
I Phy Hn        60       75
I Phy ml        76       79
```

EDIT:
I have tried several options available over internet, using VLOOKUP, RIGHT, INDEX,... But none gives me intended answer. I would prefer a solution without using helper columns. If need to use helper columns, please suggest a solution without requiring modification of my cols A:D.

For Min I have a solution MIN(VLOOKUP("II Cm2",$AE$4:$AF$171,2,0), but it requires a helper column of extracted numbers from a *single column* of my original data.

Solutions using macro/script also welcome.

Comment: max and min of what particular value?

Comment: corresponding to say "II Cm2", here min is 447 and max is 466. Hope it is clear.

Comment: Please tell why a downvote?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
See also: [ask]

Comment: Sure I will add and thanks

Comment: While not a programming solution. split the field on spaces. https://www.google.com/search?q=split+field+in+excel&oq=split+field+in+excel+&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6728j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 Then sort with an auto filter.

Comment: @user1787331 Please see the edit

Comment: @pnuts Not like that, see carefully

Comment: @user1787331 I don't need a single function or formula. One for max and one for min is needed.

Comment: Then split on spaces, and use a filter, then sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to extract only Min/Max number from range, please use this formula in cell `G2` and drag it to the bottom of values you entered in range `F2:F5`. `=MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$D$500,$F2,"")+0),SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$D$500,$F2,"")+0))` you must enter it using `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` combination since it it array formula. For Max just replace Min in formula.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But can you modify it to give the lowest/highest in the entire range? Also for 'I Phy Hn' and 'I PHY ml' separately.

Comment: Try adding if formula to adjust this to your needs.

Comment: The solution I can think of requires more helper columns. Also can't give 'I Phy Hn' and 'I PHY ml' separately.

Comment: Hi, I have adjusted answer to suit your needs. please mark as answered if you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about how to create a formula that takes a range of cells as a parameter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8663320/8112776).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7239408/8112776) is one way to return just the numbers from a string.

Here is a [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/instrrev-function) that looks for one string within another, backwards.

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/val-function) tells you about changing a string into a number.

Below is one way that you could put them together to find your 'max' value:

```
Function MaxValueOfRange(rng As Range) As Integer
    Dim c As Range, strIn As String, intRet As Integer
    For Each c In rng 'loop through each cell in range
        strIn = Right(c, Len(c) - InStrRev(c, " ")) 'get everything after the last 'space'
    Next
    If Val(strRet) > intRet Then intRet = Val(strRet) 'convert it to number and keep the biggest one
    MaxValueOfRange = intRet 'return the biggest number
End Function
```

Comment: I could not try your answer. Thank you for your efforts and answer. Accepted answer does the job easily.